# How can I mark sections of a very large `org-agenda` file as read-only?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I prefer to work in one large `org-agenda` file. I have my appointments and notes in there from the past five years. I do not want to accidentally change any parts of my old entries while adding new information. I do not like to archive entries but keep them as they are. I would like to set some headings as "read only".

How can I do that? Or how can I at least make it more difficult for me to make any accidental changes to these headings and their contents, perhaps by "locking" them somehow?

I am running Emacs 27 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some lightly improved code that preserves the modified state when applied.For me tasks that are readonly do get listed in the agenda, but I get a bell error about text being read-only. I guess org-agenda is trying to set some properties on the text or something, and is having trouble because it is read-only. I don't see a real way around that.

```
(defun org-mark-readonly ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf-mod (buffer-modified-p)))
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (org-mark-subtree)
       (add-text-properties (region-beginning) (region-end) '(read-only t)))
     "read_only")
    (unless buf-mod
      (set-buffer-modified-p nil))))


(defun org-remove-readonly ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf-mod (buffer-modified-p)))
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (let* ((inhibit-read-only t))
     (org-mark-subtree)
     (remove-text-properties (region-beginning) (region-end) '(read-only t))))
     "read_only")
    (unless buf-mod
      (set-buffer-modified-p nil))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-mark-readonly)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This updated code preserves the modified state. As you noted however, there are still problems viewing the `org-agenda` when items are marked as read_only. In my case, only some items are appearing, and I cannot move forward beyond a certain date.

Comment: If I mark the whole file as read-only using `# -*- buffer-read-only: t -*- ` (and removing the `read_only` tags) the file displays without problems in `org-agenda`.

Answer (score 0):

I did find one very useful solution since posting my question:

[Make some org-sections read-only](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/09/13/Make-some-org-sections-read-only/)

Comment: The only downside to this method is that if one then opens the file, Emacs treats it as "modified" even if no changes have been made to it.

Comment: Items so marked also do not display in org-agenda.